# "Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated" when enabling JSmallfib on Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I'm trying to use the JSmallfib PRO on Joomla 2.5. The install was successful, but when I try to enable the plugin I encounter the error

> Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in C:\wamp\www\Clap\plugins\content\jsmallfib\jsmallfib.php on line 220

...on the front and backend.

Is this normal? If not, how should I resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

On line 220 change (&$article) to ($article). Also on line 447, 686, 3518 and 3678 change &= to =. In other words, remove the pass-by-reference operator (&) since that is the default behavior of php since about php5 anyway.